# The AVAudioEngine gets data from the network and plays it with noise or silence

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioengine

I want to use the  AVAudioEngine to play the data from the network, but when I get the data from the network and use scheduleBuffer to add the data, there will be noise or the sound will simply break

```
   //init
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initWebSocket:server_ip];

    self.engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];

    self.playerNode = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
    [self.engine attachNode:self.playerNode];
    self.format = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32
                                            sampleRate:(double)48000.0
                                            channels:(AVAudioChannelCount)1
                                            interleaved:NO];

    AVAudioMixerNode *mainMixer = [self.engine mainMixerNode];

    [self.engine connect:self.playerNode to:mainMixer format:self.format];

    if (!self.engine.isRunning) {
        [self.engine prepare];
        NSError *error;
        BOOL success;
        success = [self.engine startAndReturnError:&error];
        NSAssert(success, @"couldn't start engine, %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self.playerNode play];


}

// get data from network
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message{

    NSData *data = message;
    AVAudioPCMBuffer *pcmBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc]
                                  initWithPCMFormat:self.format
                                  frameCapacity:(uint32_t)(data.length)
                                  /self.format.streamDescription->mBytesPerFrame];

    pcmBuffer.frameLength = pcmBuffer.frameCapacity;

    [data getBytes:*pcmBuffer.floatChannelData length:data.length];

    [self.playerNode scheduleBuffer:pcmBuffer completionHandler:nil];

}
```

Comment: Are you certain that the data is actually in the format you've configured? (PCM, Float32, single channel, 48kHz.)

Comment: I am sure the datat format is ok， I can use FFMPEG play it in the same format

Comment: When you say you can use FFMPEG, you mean you're explicitly calling out the format (`pcm_f32be`) and sample rate on the commandline? If the data you're getting is in a container format, FFMPEG would play it, and you'd get exactly the symptom you describe. FFMPEG is quite smart at playing random things you throw at it.

Comment: I use a command like this "ffplay song.pcm -f 32le -channels 1 -ar 48000"......I can paly normal with AudioUnit now，but, I think use AVAudioEngine is the best choice

Answer (score 0):

You set 4 times longer than data length to the `frameLength`

Your Audio format uses float (32bit).
But NSData includes UInt8 (8bit) data stream.

So, pcmBuffer.frameLength must be data.length/4.

Comment: I believe that's what the `/self.format.streamDescription->mBytesPerFrame` is doing. Have I misread something?